# ZipFile get creation date

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I would like to get the creation date of a file inside zipped folder.

I know that without zip, this can be achieved with using `os.path.getctime()` function and last modified date of a file inside zipped folder can be extracted with [`ZipInfo.date_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.date_time). But `ZipInfo` does not seem to have a way to extract the creation date.

Also, I have tried on using `ZipInfo` to get the modified date as follows.

```
# zip_file is the .zip folder
# screenshot_filename is the file inside .zip
with ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as my_zip:
    my_zip.getinfo(screenshot_filename)
```

And the `ZipInfo` object result does not contain any `date_time` information. Below is the example.

```
<ZipInfo filename='SCREEN CAP/SS.png' compress_type=deflate external_attr=0x20 file_size=555790 compress_size=504859>
```

So, did I do it wrongly or is there any better way to extract the creation date (or modified date if creation date is not possible) of a file inside zipped folder?

**UPDATE:**

I got the answer to get the last modified time/`date_time` from `ZipInfo`. Apparently, although `date_time` is not listed in the object, we can get it simply by accessing the attribute, i.e.

```
my_zip.getinfo(screenshot_filename).date_time
```

However, I am still looking for the answer for getting the creation date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default ZIP file stores only the modification date of a file (**local time** [with 2 seconds precision](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), inherited from [FAT file system limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table)). Any additional metadata can be stored in `extra` field.

> **Note:** Python does NOT decode `extra` field data, so you have to parse it yourself according to the documentation below!

The `extra` field consists of multiple data blocks which immediately follow each other. The following extra blocks can be used to store file **creation** or modification date in UTC and with more precision:

- **NTFS (0x000a);**
- UNIX (0x000d);
- **Info-ZIP Macintosh (0x334d "M3");**
- **Unix Extended Timestamp (0x5455 "UT");**
- Info-ZIP UNIX (0x5855 "UX").

(see [Info-ZIP's extra field description](https://fossies.org/linux/unzip/proginfo/extrafld.txt) for more info)

> **Note:** As of Python 3.7 `zipfile` module reads file information only from ZIP's central directory file header, so you may have problems getting dates from some third-party extra blocks.
> However, you could get `extra` field data from local file header yourself using `header_offset` field.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20125880/11725753) to set the creation date when you extract it.