# Linux - modify file modify/access/change time

Tags: linux, metadata, steganography

I read an article about new steganographic method: "Time is on my side: Steganography in filesystem metadata" http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287616300433. It is very interesting and makes me thinking about one thing.

Is it possible to manipulate file modify/access/change time metedata using C or any other language in Linux OS?
I found method which is using ***touch*** command, but it creates file with specific tag value. I would like to find way to modify this metadata in existing one.

Comment: look at `man touch` more carefully

Comment: @IporSircer I've just found an answer. My question can be closed :)

Comment: Krystian, this site is supposed to be a repository for knowledge in a Q&A format. If you've found an answer to your question, while this question may feel unnecessary to you now, you're still encouraged to [write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for the benefit of any future readers. Unless you deem the question too trivial to answer or it already has a duplicate on the site, in which case you should flag it thusly.

Answer (score 10):

Using **touch** command you can edit time metadata of files. Example:

```
touch -a -t 201611161200.10 file.txt
```

It will result in modifing access timestamp, and replace it with date 2016-11-16 12:00:10.000000000
To change 'Modify' date you should use flag **-m**

Answer (score 6):

I came across this thread and I had to share my findings (as mentioned this site is a repository for knowledge):

- "**touch**" is a command line application and in order to execute it (from c++ application) you need to run system() which is **discouraged**.
  more on touch: http://www.linfo.org/touch.html
- **The programmatic way** to set the access and modification timestamps of a file is using one of the following system calls: **utime, utimes, futimes, futimens** (simple internet search will give you the man page of them)
  i.e http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=2&topic=utimensat
- **Linux has 3 time stamps associated to a file**:

  1. Access - the last time the file was read
  2. Modify - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)
  3. Change - the last time meta data of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)
     extra reading here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file/2465#2465?newreg=b4e0ee2ef0734b8792240c205e420c55
- It's relatively easy to modify the 'access' and 'modify' timestamps using the above commands, but modifying the change timestamp (last time permissions were changed) is harder. Thread on this here:
  [Setting creation or change timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537291/setting-creation-or-change-timestamps)

Comment: See also `lutimes()` if you want to correctly handle symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

```
touch -c -m --date="2022-02-19 10:00" /path/to/your/file
```