# System programming, create two files with same time access and permissions

Tags: c, file

Create a file foo and foo2 with the same time access and permissions using system programming.
I am quite clueless about this, I had to create foo and foo2 outside, and now I am unsure whether this is the correct way to do it or not.
This is what I have tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("./foo", O_RDWR);
    
    int fd2 = open("./foo2", O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("\nError creating foo.");
    }
    else if(fd2 == -1)
    {
        printf("\nError creating foo2.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nFile descripter 1:     %d", fd);  
        printf("\nFile descripter 2:     %d", fd2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42214603/898348

Comment: "Using system programming" means (e.g.) writing code that understands and modifies the contents of raw physical disk blocks. Using high level APIs built on top of abstractions (which are then provided to user-space), is not system programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux - modify file modify/access/change time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630695/linux-modify-file-modify-access-change-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of file creation, the C command is `open()`, as stated in it's man page (requires some libs, beware):

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

If the user wishes to create or override the file, he may use `creat()`, which is in reality little more than `open()` with these flags: `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`

As for time access, others dwellers may be more helpful; Jabberwocky's link may be of some help.

Comment: *requires some libs* Huh?  `open()` is almost always in the implicitly-linked-unless-you-tell-it-otherwise `libc.so` library.