# Changing qcow2 st_ctime

Tags: qemu, guest-executable

Is there a way to modify the st_ctime_sec attributes for a qcow2 image?

I am trying to have a reproducible qcow2 build, with the end goal being that I can recreate qcow2 files and still have byte for byte identical contents.

I am down to have the ctime's being different between my original and my reproduction build.

Using 
virt-diff -a orig.qcow2 -A rebuild.qcow2  --atime --dir-times --times 
I only get differences like:

## changed: st_ctime_sec

- d 0755       4096 2017-11-21 22:35:00 2017-11-21 22:35:00 2017-11-22 02:34:36 /boot/efi/EFI
- d 0755       4096 2017-11-21 22:35:00 2017-11-21 22:35:00 2017-11-22 11:10:48 /boot/efi/EFI

I found a solution that works as root, but I am looking for something that can be run as a normal user.

From [mount qcow as device](https://michaelmk.blogspot.ca/2011/12/howto-mount-qcow2-images.html)

```
 modprobe nbd max_part=8
 qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 guest.img
 mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/guest
```

Then from [change ctime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36021/how-can-i-change-change-date-of-file)

```
debugfs -w  /dev/sda1 < changes
```

where changes contains lines like

```
set_inode_field /grub2/locale/ast.mo ctime 201001010101
set_inode_field /grub2/locale/ca.mo ctime 201001010101
set_inode_field /grub2/locale/da.mo ctime 201001010101
set_inode_field /grub2/locale/de.mo ctime 201001010101
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do atime and mtime with the libguestfs API [guestfs_utimens](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs.3.html#guestfs_utimens).  However ctime is not settable with libguestfs, largely because [it appears there is not a "good" way to do it in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537291/setting-creation-or-change-timestamps).  You could code up the `debugfs` approach as a new libguestfs API (or use the debug backdoor).  Or if your image is a raw filesystem (not qcow2) you might just run `debugfs` directly on it, and then copy the raw filesystem into the final image using the guestfs upload API (the opposite of [this](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-recipes.1.html#dump-raw-filesystem-content-from-inside-a-disk-image-or-vm)).