# why does the touch command also change ctime?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

```bash
# stat main.c
Access: 2023-12-14 23:43:08.299761676 +0800
Modify: 2023-12-14 23:43:08.274761678 +0800
Change: 2023-12-14 23:43:08.274761678 +0800
 Birth: -

# touch main.c
# stat main.c (all the three times changed.)
Access: 2023-12-14 23:43:37.956758479 +0800
Modify: 2023-12-14 23:43:37.893758486 +0800
Change: 2023-12-14 23:43:37.893758486 +0800
 Birth: -

# for -a option,atime and ctime will change.
# for -m option,atime mtime,ctime all three will change.
```

I am confused about why does the touch command also change ctime?

```bash
touch changes the access and/or modification timestamps of the specified files.
(As you can see,only atime and mtime are mentioned.)

# options:
-a. Change the access timestamp only.
-m. Change the modification timestamp only.

# https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/touch-invocation.html
```

So I am confused.

And after the touch command,the content of main.c is the same as before.

But the mtime has changed.(I cannot understand.)

Answer (score 2):

A summary that I think is correct after lots of googling and reading existing answers to similar questions:

`touch` only has options to modify `atime` (access time) and `mtime` (modification time), both simultaneously by default, because they are the only 2 timestamps a user should modify and can set to any specific timestamp they like while `ctime` (change time) is intended to be the current system time when the file was changed (and so by design it's harder for a user to set to a specific time).

`ctime` (**C**hange time) is not set when `atime` is set because neither the file's contents nor attributes (apart from `atime`) have been set and so nothing about the file has **C**hanged.

`ctime` is modified when `mtime` is set because `mtime` is an attribute of the file's meta-data, and `ctime` is set when any of the file's meta-data is set, other than `atime`.

In addition to the above, though, unlike other commands that update the access timestamp such as `cat`, `touch` always updates `ctime` even if called with `-a` to only update the access time and even if no timestamps actually changed, note when the timestamps change below:

```
$ printf 'Hello World\n' > file

$ stat file | tail -4
Access: 2023-12-14 11:13:06.850045900 -0600
Modify: 2023-12-14 11:13:06.850045900 -0600
Change: 2023-12-14 11:13:06.850958200 -0600
 Birth: 2023-11-28 09:06:22.968048500 -0600

$ cat file
Hello World

$ stat file | tail -4
Access: 2023-12-14 11:13:21.743099800 -0600 <- changed
Modify: 2023-12-14 11:13:06.850045900 -0600
Change: 2023-12-14 11:13:06.850958200 -0600
 Birth: 2023-11-28 09:06:22.968048500 -0600

$ touch -a file

$ stat file | tail -4
Access: 2023-12-14 11:13:49.667423400 -0600 <- changed
Modify: 2023-12-14 11:13:06.850045900 -0600
Change: 2023-12-14 11:13:49.667271500 -0600 <- changed
 Birth: 2023-11-28 09:06:22.968048500 -0600
```

Regarding [the OPs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77660964/why-does-the-touch-command-also-change-ctime/77661853#comment136914160_77661091):

> I am also confused that touch doesnot modify the file's content,but
> mtime is changed.why?

because you told it to. `touch` is the command you call to update a files modification and/or access time, so that's what it does when you call it.

For more information see:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/touch-invocation.html
- [why-does-touch-a-also-set-the-ctime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316386/why-does-touch-a-also-set-the-ctime/316387#316387)
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html
- [Setting creation or change timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4537291/1745001)
- https://smarttech101.com/relatime-atime-noatime-strictatime-lazytime/

Answer (score 0):

touch is specified as changing file access and modification times; changing the change time is a side-effect of the change to the file's metadata, and touch doesn't have any control over that (see also the futimens() and utimensat() functions used by touch).

Comment: Why is this change a necessary side effect? AFIK, the ctime is the time where the file's inode information has been changed, while mtime is the time where the data in  the file has changed.  Why does the latter necessarily imply the former?

Comment: @user1934428，And I am also confused that touch doesnot modify the file's content,but mtime is changed.why?

Comment: @hhx: Now this starts making sense: By definition, touch allows you to explicitly set an arbitrary timestamp for the mtime of a file, to simulate that a file has been modified at a certain time. Therefore, mtime is chaged by functionality of touch. HOWEVER, timestamps are part of the inode data, and whenever you change a timestamp for whatever reason, you also have an inode change, and with this the ctime also gets updated.

Comment: @user1934428
Does this means that whether I change the atime or the mtime, the ctime will change?

Comment: @hhx : I was thinking the same. Right now I'm not at a Linux system, so I can't verify it.

Comment: @htx no, `cat file` will update it's `atime` but neither `mtime` nor `ctime` while `printf '' > file` will update `mtime` and `ctime` but not `atime` and `touch file` will update all 3.

Comment: @EdMorton although `relatime` mount option (and others) can affect that behaviour

Comment: See [the original answer that the content of this answer was copied from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316387/133219) for more information.

Comment: @hhx: Perhaps this is a bit fuzzily defined. When looking at [man 7 inode](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html), we see that **1.** _atime_ is considered part of the inode information, and **2.** _ctime_ "is changed by writing or by setting inode information", so this leads me to guess, that chainging atime should update ctime as well, but as Ed Morton found out, this is not the case.

Comment: @user1934428 right, I almost believed the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225213/133219 until I had that "but what about `atime`?" realization.

Comment: @EdMorton, cat command does not change the three time.You can have a try.

Comment: @user1934428 but directly above we see that atime is changed "by file accesses", not by "writing or by setting inode information" (which I take to refer to explicit user action)

Comment: @hhx I didn't say that `cat` would change the 3 times, I said it'd only update `atime`.

Comment: @hhx check mount options. `relatime` reduces the frequency of atime being modified; `noatime` disables it entirely

Comment: @hhx: Well, I found in [man 2 utimensat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html) the explicit statement: _The status change time (ctime) will be set to the current time,  even if the other time stamps don't actually change._ The "other time stamps" are the atime and the mtime. And _utimensat_ is used by `touch`, and it is POSIX.